# NodeJs keystrokes get printed twice in console

Tags: node.js, input, console

I'm new to NodeJs and i'm used to C# were we can use 
`Console.ReadLine();`

I looked into 'readline' and the node prompt package, but it either outputs all the user input twice while entering or, with the 'terminal: false' option, does not allow us to use the backspace.

Comment: Not exactly, i had the peculiar case that the console's output was doubled on every letter input. Probably that was an issue in conjunction with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] then of the code that doubles the input? Thanks. The answers here and the one you accepted are essentially the same as the suggested dupe.

Comment: No sorry i can't. This question was asked 5 years ago.. But as far as i remember and my comments state the code from the answer was producing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a readline, you can use it like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('How are you today? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

Documentation is available [here](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).

Comment: @F.H. the code provided allows backspacing, and does not run into any of the issues outlined in your question.

Comment: If i type 'Hello World' i get 'HHeelllloo  WWoorrlldd', don't know about you but i guess it's the same right?

Comment: I do not get that. What OS and terminal are you using?

Comment: Sorry for my response then. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm referring to the output before hitting enter.

Comment: That's a bizarre issue! It's probably an issue with the terminal then, and not with the code. See if you have a setting called echo turned on, that may be the cause.

Comment: Can't find that setting. Strange, but now it makes sense that i find so little about this issue on the internet. It's a fresh installation of Ubuntu too.

Comment: Very weird. The folks in AskUbuntu may know more about it, I don't use Ubuntu personally.

Answer (score 4):

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    console.log("your input: " + d.toString());
});
```

This is like you take input value