# Reference Error showing prompt is not defined

Tags: javascript, prompt

store input numbers

```js
const num1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter the first number '));
const num2 = parseInt(prompt('Enter the second number '));

//add two numbers
const sum = num1 + num2;

console.log(`The sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`);
```

display the sum

```
console.log(`The sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`);
```

Comment: instead use [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline) if you're working on nodejs not browser.

Answer (score 0):

The default prompt and window are not defined in the node environment.
But if you want to use `prompt-sync` try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394928/get-user-input-through-node-js-console)