# How can fix the requested url line in the code?

Tags: node.js-connect

Here, I am trying to write a program in node.js to parse the given url.Basically here it should show if the connection is established or not . once it shows the connection the established,it should request for the url to parsed , all this would happen in the command prompt. Then when we go on the page it would show- The parse url is:"url".
But currently the connection gets established but its not requesting for the url to be parsed.

```
var port = 5050;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url !== '/favicon.ico' && req.url !== '/') {
        console.log('Requested URL: ' + req.url);
    }

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write("The Parse url is : " + req.url);
    res.end();
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:5050/');
});
```

Comment: [What is the exact problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO4eb.png) ?

Comment: As you can see the code there is a line requested url ,this should should a requested url demand in the command prompt once the connection is established with the local server but that is not happening.The connection gets established but I am not able to parse the url

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. When starting the script (using`node script.js`), and then visiting `http://localhost:5050/somehting` Is do see: `The Parse url is : /somehting` in my browser.   Can you use [edit] to add more info about your expectations?

Comment: The purpose of the code is being able to parse a url. Now when you run the file in command prompt,if connection is established in command prompt it will display "server running at  http://localhost:5050/" then in next line it should display Requested url:"here you would paste the url that you want to parse". Now issue connection is getting established but Requested Url part is not happening. If it works your browser would display The Parse url is : "The url that you pasted in command prompt "

Comment: see: [Get user input through Node.js console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394928/get-user-input-through-node-js-console)